# Magento 2. In Search Repeating Error

Tags: magento2, frontend, search

i tried to override the Search for that my Layout is

> catalogsearch_result_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body> 
        <referenceContainer name="content"> 
             <block class="Vender\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Vender_Module::product/list.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

just to override the Search Page not all the categories.So now when I Override the Price Function to show just a text for testing. then in search it shows like [image]
As you guys can see in the image it is showing a product twice after that I add a custom **Khan** tag in the **phtml** file then it shows like you guys can see in the image that the Khan is showing in the 2nd one not the first one I just want my Own phtml file to work on this page. Thanks in Advance for Help

Comment: Override the `phtml` file in your theme so you don't need to write the XML code as well.

Comment: This is because you have create your custom layout and adding the phtml under default Container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Answer as we know that in **referenceBlock** we cannot declare our own class so we have to do it like

> catalogsearch_result_list

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="search_result_list" template="Vender_Module::product/list.phtml">
        <block class="Vender\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="dummy"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like you have copied the code from `catalog_category_view.xml` and put it into your `catalogsearch_result_index.xml`. With that code you just add an additional product list (with the content of the current product collection) to the search result page.

If you want to overwite the search block your block must be named `search.result` not `category.products.list`. But just by renaming that you will see your block but no toolbar and all the other stuff related to search result page.

I guess what you want to do, is copy the xml for the `search_result_list` block from `catalogsearch_result_index.xml` (with all arguments and nested blocks!) and change your template there